# How many Jolokia agents needs to be installed?

Tags: java, jmx, jolokia

Suppose I have 8 java server applications (actually instances of the same java application) running in 4 linux boxes ( 2 each). I want to be able to monitor these applications from another linux box using Jolokia.

I also need the ability to start and stop these java applications. Can Jolokia help here?

Do I need to install one Jolokia war agent on a linux box to monitor all those 8 applications mentioned above? Or do I need to install war agent in each of the four linux boxes? Or do I need to attach jolokia JVM agent to each of the 8 java applications?
Do I need to change anything in my original java applications to use Jolokia for above purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I also need the ability to start and stop these java applications. Can Jolokia help here?

Jolkia doesn't allow you to start services.  You could implement a custom jmx command to stop a service though, and invoke that through Jolokia.

Jolokia is pretty flexible in how you use it.  You could set up 1 Jolokia [proxy](http://www.jolokia.org/features/proxy.html) on any machine, and query the 8 jvms through the one proxy. You could also set up a proxy on each linux machine.

Using a proxy means you don't have to modify your application, except perhaps to add [command line arguments to expose jmx remotely](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/jconsole.html).

You could also package Jolokia with each jvm.  How you do it depends on your application, and there are instructions [here](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/agents.html).